# Inverse Laplace, residue, simple or essential pole from bivaluated hyperbolic trigonometric function?

Tags: residue-calculus, hyperbolic-functions, inverse-laplace

I would like to compute the following function:
$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\Big[\frac{1}{s(e^{a+\text{arcosh}(s+\cosh a)}-1)}\Big](t)$$

However, it seems that there is no other pole than the pole of order one $s=0$, which gives a residue without $t$-dependence.
I guess that I should consider that $\text{arcosh}(\cosh a)=\pm a$, in which case it seems (always for the negative case) that the pole is essential.

Why should I consider that $\text{arcosh}$ is negative?
How can I compute this residue anyway?

Comment: What is $\text{acosh}$ is that the same as $\text{arccosh}?$

Comment: Yes indeed, I correct the notation.